# PHP Array convert and simplify multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array below and would like to organize it like this: category 22 contains 783,784,785. category 11 contains 783,784,785 and so on. I am kinda stuck...
So below is the source and below that is what I want to transform the array to.

```
Array
(
    [783] = Array
        (
            [categories] = Array
                (
                    [0] = 22
                    [1] = 11
                    [2] = 12
                )

        )

    [784] = Array
        (
            [categories] = Array
                (
                    [0] = 22
                    [1] = 11
                    [2] = 12
                )

        )

    [785] = Array
        (
            [categories] = Array
                (
                    [0] = 22
                    [1] = 11
                    [2] = 12
                )

        )

)
```

Would like to transform the array to this.

```
Array
    (
        [22] = Array
            (
                [0] => 783
                [1] => 784   
                [2] => 785
            )

        [11] = Array
            (
                [0] => 783
                [1] => 784   
                [2] => 785
            )

        [12] = Array
            (
                [0] => 783
                [1] => 784   
                [2] => 785
            )
    )
```

Comment: what's the original source of the data?

Comment: The code that I post is the original

Comment: You basically want to switch the second layer for the first, yes?

Comment: yes, minus the category layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just iterate over the original array and assemble the result; something like this:

```
$categories = array();

foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemData) {
        foreach ($itemData['categories'] as $categoryId) {
                $categories[$categoryId][] = $itemId;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you can do something like that. I was trying to do something similar except I had 3 foreach going on instead of 2. Thanks again!